# SQL Server instance stopped responding

Tags: sql-server, instance

I created a SQL Server instance in my cloud a few days ago for the 1st time.
Today for no apparent reason this instance stopped responding and presents a revolving wait sign for hours now.

I created successfully another instance but the first one does still does not respond.

Could not find a way to reboot it or make it work again.

Any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Lots of questions... what cloud provider, Windows Server?  If Windows, take a look at the event viewer. https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson3/

Comment: Sorry I did not mention it is google mssql2017 cloud.